What type of hydraulic pump for a low rpm, low power motor?
I am attempting to power a 20 ton hydraulic press with a hydraulic pump powered by a stationary bicycle. I know I have plenty of power (in fact, much more leg power compared to one arm pumping a lever on normal press), which will be in the 500-1000 watt range for the short duration.
I expect to use bicycle gearing to have a final output around 500rpms.
What pump is recommended for low rpms like that? From what I've learned, a gear pump is the best for cost/function.
Or would I be better off adding another gearing multiplier and aim for 1500rpm? (might be excessive for chains)
I'm looking for the highest efficiency, with keeping cost reasonable and easy to source parts.
It looks like I can get 1gpm at 2000psi with 85% efficiency at around 1000watts. I'm not sure I can find such a low flow rate pump?
Thanks for any input!

"... which will be in the 500-1000 watt range for the short duration." That would be considered impressive for an athlete. You might want to scale back your optimism somewhat. Have a look at https://www.cyclinganalytics.com/blog/2018/06/how-does-your-cycling-power-output-compare.

I think that's accurate. A human man can reasonably put out 250W for an hour working aerobically. Going full anaerobic, for say 10 seconds, the output of that same man could easily be 4 times that.

I had a feeling the subject would go towards "get real, you can't do that wattage". I'm talking about 10 to 30 seconds bursts, you know - the time it might take to do a reasonable pressing action on a press - which is the actual intended use. That's why I said short duration. And yes, I've biked with a power meter for years. Though I'm not able to do what I could in my younger years, 1000w is still not hard for 10 seconds.

Get a 1HP or 2HP hydraulic pressure pump, take the motor off, and build a really efficient 30:1 drivetrain (I'm assuming a high cadence -- if you put out your 1.3HP at 60 RPM, then go for 60:1).
Done.
If you want to do this on the cheap, shop around for a used one that has a burnt out motor but looks like it has a good pump.  You should be able to get a cheap brand for scrap prices, or a quality brand for the cost of a cheap one.
